# How to prevent automatic redirection of 404 errors and "incorrect" URLs?

Tags: redirect, urls, 404-error, rel-canonical

Wordpress has a feature whereby it will automatically redirect your URLs if it percieves them to be written wrongly. Here is an example: I have a page called `my-page`

If I go to:

```
www.mysite.com/something/my-page/
```

it will immediately redirect me to

```
www.mysite.com/my-page/
```

as nothing exists at the first URL.

How can I turn this feature off, and instead just get a 404 if incorrect URL's are typed in?

Comment: If you watch what is happening (via HttpFox or WireShark or a similar packet sniffer), those pages redirect with a 301 Status-- Moved Permanently-- which is appropriate behavior. It helps search engines keep their databases up to date among other things, and the redirect helps users find pages. This may effect how WordPress handles things when you actually do move a page or change a permalink, so be careful. Anyway, your choice but I am not sure it is a good idea.

Comment: I know it's a good thing, I do understand that. However, I have a particular use case where I did not need that behaviour. I am developing a plugin which handles URL redirection and so I want to override that behavior.

Comment: Here is a more correct answer: [link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/92103/disable-wordpress-url-auto-complete#answer-92104)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
remove_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

Comment: Can you guide me for what it will do? what is canonical redirect? i am new to wordpress

Comment: You just saved me a lot of headaches! thank you ! :-D

Comment: Is there nowhere where we can see these redirects so that we can remove them on a one by one basis?

Comment: This is great. Do you know why `wp-admin` might still be redirecting after using this?

Comment: You can find a detailed explanation of this issue at https://www.dev4press.com/blog/wordpress/2015/canonical-redirect-problem-and-solutions/

Comment: I believe it should be remove_filter instead of remove_action.

Answer (score 11):

As Ash suggested, you can turn off the feature by using the following code:

```
remove_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

In looking at the redirect_canonical function in canonical.php, it would appear you can also modify the behavior with your own filter.

At the end of the redirect_canonical() function, there is a call to filter the final answer:

```
$redirect_url = apply_filters( 'redirect_canonical', $redirect_url, $requested_url );
```

So you could write your own filter to modify the final redirection or return null to stop the redirection, based upon the input, thus **turning off** the feature for a particular URL or a subset of URLs.

Comment: This [SO](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/326553/181880) shows more details on how to add a filter for those like myself who are a bit new to WP

Answer (score 5):

You can disable permalink guessing for 404s without disabling redirection of canonical URLs by adding the following line somewhere in your code (eg. in `functions.php`):

```
add_filter('do_redirect_guess_404_permalink', '__return_false');
```

Relevant functions in the Wordpress code are [`redirect_canonical`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/redirect_canonical/) and [`redirect_guess_404_permalink`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/redirect_guess_404_permalink/) in `wp-includes/canonical.php`.

Comment: Interestingly the docs seem outdated, because it says `redirect_canonical` is for both TLD-level redirects and also for 404 error redirects...

Comment: @JesseNickles, Yes, `redirect_canonical` calls `redirect_guess_404_permalink` if the page is a 404, but it does other redirects as well.