# Disable Wordpress URL auto complete

Tags: redirect, urls

I recently noticed that Wordpress tries to auto-complete a URL when it's not submitted in its entirety. E.g. I have a post URL that looks like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/some-post-title
```

If I browse to the following URL:

```
http://www.mysite.com/some-post-ti
```

I can see that the URL is submitted to Wordpress but that Wordpress is doing a 301 redirect to `http://www.mysite.com/some-post-title`.

How can I disable this behavior?

Comment: A tested solution that does not disable the whole canonical URL system but only disables the autocomplete "guessing" part is outlined [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/144970/51898)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I believe that is the [`redirect_canonical`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/redirect_canonical) function hooked to `template_redirect`. You should be able to disable it with:

```
remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

But you should really think about whether you want to do that as it is fairly complicated and performs some important SEO functions:

> Redirects incoming links to the proper URL based on the site url.
>
> Search engines consider www.somedomain.com and somedomain.com to be
>   two different URLs when they both go to the same location. This SEO
>   enhancement prevents penalty for duplicate content by redirecting all
>   incoming links to one or the other.
>
> Prevents redirection for feeds, trackbacks, searches, comment popup,
>   and admin URLs. Does not redirect on non-pretty-permalink-supporting
>   IIS 7, page/post previews, WP admin, Trackbacks, robots.txt, searches,
>   or on POST requests.
>
> Will also attempt to find the correct link when a user enters a URL
>   that does not exist based on exact WordPress query. Will instead try
>   to parse the URL or query in an attempt to figure the correct page to
>   go to.
>
> http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/canonical.php#L13

The following ***might*** kill the autocompletion without messing with the SEO component, but I can't promise that. **The code is barely tested** as I have never wished to disable this. I'd really have to study `redirect_canonical` to be sure of anything.

```
function kill_404_redirect_wpse_92103() {
  if (is_404()) {
   add_action('redirect_canonical','__return_false');
  }
}
add_action('template_redirect','kill_404_redirect_wpse_92103',1);
```

Comment: I added this code snippet to the end of my /wp-includes/canonical.php file and the redirects are still happening. Am I doing something wrong? Anyone else unable to disable this behaviour?

Comment: @user1380540 you don't edit core files. this would go to a theme functions.php or to a plugin.

Comment: another reason I have a love / hate relationship with wordpress

Answer (score 6):

This seems terribly irresponsible, to have this "guessing" occur automatically. I would be much more open to it if there were some means of defining which was the correct page to go to.

I have numerous pages that are built as a sequence, and this auto-guessing is incorrectly choosing to respond with pages that are (randomly?) somewhere in the sequence, as opposed to the starting page.

UPDATE: This is known behavior, and is being considered here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16557

Answer (score 2):

As a follow up to FitPM's answer - a plugin has been created that disables the auto-guessing behavior.

It works fine for me on Wordpress 4.8 as of August 2, 2017. The plugin is here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-url-autocorrect-guessing/

Answer (score 1):

One note: If one disables redirect_canonical (e.g. with `remove_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');`), random links like https://tld.com/some-random-string/blogpost also work (the content of https://tld.com/real-category-slug/blogpost is shown).

If you want to prevent that and return 404 on those random urls, use something like

```php
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', function( $redirect_url ) {
    $url = 'http'.((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])&&$_SERVER['HTTPS']!=='off')?'s':'').'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if( $redirect_url !== $url ) {
        global $wp_query;
        $wp_query->set_404();
        status_header( 404 );
        nocache_headers();
    }
    return false; 
});
```

Comment: you can simplify it by
$url = home_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );