# Wordpress redirects non-existing url to existing ones - how to disable

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, urls, wp-redirect

I've noticed that when I type:

`http://domain.tld/c` *(which does not exist)*

somehow, for some reason I'm directed to

`http://domain.tld/contact` *(which exists)*

I found that this is default behavior at least in recent versions of Wordpress.

How to control-disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a duplicate of [Disable ONLY URL auto complete, not the whole canonical URL system](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144937/disable-only-url-auto-complete-not-the-whole-canonical-url-system?rq=1)

Try this filter

```
function remove_redirect_guess_404_permalink( $redirect_url ) {
if ( is_404() )
    return false;
return $redirect_url;
}

add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', 'remove_redirect_guess_404_permalink' );
```

Or this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-url-autocorrect-guessing/