# WP is redirecting instead of going to 404

Tags: 404-error

Why is wordpress redirecting to an existing page if the uri is staring like an existing page  instead of redirecting to a 404 ?

Example, i have theses pages

> mysite.com/aeroport
>
> mysite.com/intralog

But if I go to

> mysite.com/aeroport/intra

Instead of going to a 404, WP is redirecting me to the translated english version of intralog

> mysite.com/en/intralog

Same if I do **mysite.com/aeroport/medi**, it's redirecting me to **mysite.com/medias** instead of a 404

I'm using polylang, I can't disable it, but all my other plugin are disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does [this WPSE article](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144937/disable-only-url-auto-complete-not-the-whole-canonical-url-system/144970#144970) help?

Looking at this article and similar, I'd recommend reading up on the purpose of this feature as you *may* not want to (fully) disable it.

Comment: great that's it ! been stuck all day on that.