# Disable "similar permalink" redirect

Tags: permalinks, multisite, redirect

I have set a post to private on a WordPress multisite so users should be redirected to a 404 page. The permalink of this post is `http://local.website.com/en/event`.

Now WordPress seems to redirect requests to `event` to `event-30-01-2016`. WordPress seems to focus on the lower number after the `event` string. Example: it will prioritise `event-29-05-2015` over `event-30-05-2015`.

I want to keep the URLs for posts like `event-*` but I want `event` to redirect to 404 since I kind of disabled the page.

My settings on `/wp-admin/options-permalink.php` are set to `Post name`.

I don't have any special rewriteRules in `.htaccess` for events.

This is my `.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Is there maybe a hook that I could use in order to disable this kind of redirection?

Comment: Try this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71927/how-to-prevent-automatic-redirection

Comment: @Nikolay oh.. thank you a lot! I'll add the script in the answer that helped me. Or maybe you would like to answer the question? `remove_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');` helped me

Comment: You don’t want to completely remove canonical redirection! Check for your specific case and only remove it for those requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To completely disable this feature, use this code, which I got from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71927/how-to-prevent-automatic-redirection).

```
remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );
```

To only disable it for URL addresses that contain the string 'event', use this code:

```
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', 'disable_redirect_canonical_for_event', 2, 10 );

function disable_redirect_canonical_for_event( $redirect_url, $requested_url ) {
    if ( strpos( $requested_url, 'event' ) !== false ) {
        return false;
    }
    return $redirect_url;
}
```

Comment: It’s a bad idea to completely disable canonical redirection, which could result in SEO issues. You should check for the specific case you want to disable.

Comment: @Milo OK, I added another solution too now.