# How to remove canonical url in wordpress? add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', '__return_false' ); not Working for me

Tags: functions

How to remove default canonical URL in WordPress.

I'm using Yoast SEO and I tried with `add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', '__return_false' );` And also I tried with `remove_action('wp_head', 'rel_canonical');`

But not working.

Comment: How is it not working? Are you trying to cancel the default canonical redirects in WordPress?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to give my own one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WordPress, there's a function named [`redirect_canonical()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/redirect_canonical/) which basically:

> Redirects incoming links to the proper URL based on the site URL.

And by default, the function is hooked to `template_redirect`:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );
```

So you can cancel/disable the default canonical redirects in WordPress like so:

```
remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );
```

---

However, if you're just trying to set a custom canonical redirect *URL*, then you can use the [`redirect_canonical`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/redirect_canonical/) filter which is fired in the `redirect_canonical()` function:

```
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', function( $redirect_url, $requested_url ){
    if ( put expression here ) {
        // Do something with $redirect_url.
        $redirect_url = 'custom URL here';
    }

    return $redirect_url;
}, 10, 2 );
```

But the Yoast SEO plugin is already filtering the canonical URL, so this should also work:

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', function( $redirect_url ){
    if ( put expression here ) {
        // Do something with $redirect_url.
        $redirect_url = 'custom URL here';
    }

    return $redirect_url;
} );
```

*But note that Yoast SEO doesn't pass the `$requested_url` parameter; i.e. the original URL.*